# Ubuntu 13.10 constant crashing

Tags: 13.10

Morning,

I am  a new user to ubuntu and Linux in General. I have recently installed ubuntu 13.10 onto my system. This was difficult in its self as I had to make sure it was offline or it would fail on the grub installation constantly. I can get in and use the terminal but if I use anything else it freezes that screen then it freezes my mouse and I am unable to do anything e.g. Access the terminal cancel some programs. Literally nothing, I have to hard reset it. The freezing also happens if I just live boot it from my USB. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Configuration: 
Intel i7 2770k 
8gb DDR3
Nvidia 590gtx 
2.0tb HDD

Installation was via a USB drive. I used the installation process that was outlined on the ubuntu website however I didn't connect to the internet when installing. I received no errors when installing offline. If I connected before I installed then I would get grub 2 installation error.

In a attempt to try and fix this I made sure everything is updated via the terminal and this was the same with the graphics driver however ubuntu just boots into blackness and all I have is a black cross for a mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step might be to see what's going on. Try to change the GRUB boot options:

- While machine is booting press shift
- When the GRUB boot menu comes up select the second entry
- There you can choose between normal and recovery boot
- Select the first entry and press 'e'
- Now you can remove for example *quiet splash*
  which will give you more information while booting your machine.

-- Regards.

@see:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2